# Kali Linux not Updating

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I am trying to update my kali linux version, but whenever I try to execute `sudo apt update` command, it gives me the following output:

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:5 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease                                                                   
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu groovy Release                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:6 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                 
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried to update my `/etc/apt/resources.list` file, but still the same problem, I do not even know what are these ubuntu messages in the output. Now the `resources.list` file is as follows:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Make sure you're using the right file. Also make sure there are no files ending with `.list` in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.d` (maybe rename them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources.list` isn't a file that apt checks unless Kali did something *spectacularly* unwise.

The correct file is `/etc/apt/sources.list/`, and more recent versions will also look for files matching `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

The output you're showing suggests that apt is trying to read from multiple Ubuntu repositories, and throwing a series of errors because it does not have the corresponding GPG keys in its trusted list -- which it *shouldn't*, because Kali is not Ubuntu and trying to install one into the other leads to all kinds of messes.

Fix your repository settings to only use the kali link and try again.

Alternately, bear in mind that [Kali is *not* meant for general desktop usage](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) and reinstall with a proper desktop oriented system.

Comment: I renamed the `sources.list` file and still the same error. I am using kali for my cybersecurity course. Can you please tell me how to fix these repository settings?

Comment: I already did. Look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as well.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I found an application repository file that used some ubuntu and debian repository links.

Comment: Yeah, don't use those on a kali system. They kind of assume you're using an actual full distribution rather than an overgrown pentesting kit and they don't work right otherwise.